# cannot see my CUPS printer in system dialog

Tags: printing, chromium, cups, epson, yocto

I can't see cups printer in system-dialog but I am able to see my cups printer in chromiums print interface. When I select the printer and then hit the print button, nothing happens. There is no error_log in cups server. Also I can reach printer over the terminal and print every file format with lpr command. My CUPS version is 1.4.6 and using Epson TM-T20 thermal receipt printer. Chromium version is 37.0.2062.94 and libpdf is installed. I think that system cannot reach my printer. Also running on yocto os. All I got to resolv this is issue is 3 lines of Chrome logs :

```
[19001:19001:0511/231605:VERBOSE1:print_dialog_gtk2.cc(292)] Using custom paper size
[45:46:0511/231606:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(385)] Canceling pending sends
[19001:19023:0511/231606:WARNING:raw_channel_posix.cc(214)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also wonder the answers. Did you find your solution?

Comment: @alpi any update on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was gtk+ interface. Firstly, I installed cups-filters package after that, I added ghostscript and ghostscipt-cups as a RDEPENDS(running dependency) into both epson printer and chromium bitbake recipes. Finally, the real problem that not seeing printer in system-dialog, so I find out that's because of gtk+ interface. You have to override cups flag in gtk bbappend(or bb) with  `EXTRA_OECONF = "--enable-cups"` also add a dependency to cups `+DEPENDS += " cups "`. That was my solution, I hope that works for your problems.